# MSSQL query with too many paramers in IN clause is very slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, jpa, criteria, database-performance

I'm having a query with IN clause with 2000 parameters of varchar2 type. I have applied required index as per execution plan.
It is working very slowly. I'm looking for an alternative solution. One way I found is creating a temporary table with these value and fetch using join. Is there any way other than this? I'm using spring data JPA/Criteria for queries in Java. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Storing the values in a temporary table is the way to go here.

Answer (score 1):

Bulk Load the values into a temprary table, either using [SqlServerBulkCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-bulk-copy-with-the-jdbc-driver?view=sql-server-ver15) directly or using the [useBulkCopyForBatchInsert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/use-bulk-copy-api-batch-insert-operation?view=sql-server-ver15).

Use a [Table-Valued Parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-table-valued-parameters?view=sql-server-ver15)

Or (SQL 2016+) send the values as a JSON array.  Just create a long string of the form

```
["Value1","Value2","Value3"]
```

and pass it as a parameter to a query like:

```
select *
from SomeTable
where SomeColumn in ( select value from openjson(@jsonValues) with (value varchar(200) '$') )
```

Or do the same thing with [XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15).

You can also use [string_split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), but that's also only available on SQL 2016+ and JSON is more robust.